# Let Django access serial port in Lubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, permissions, serial-port

So, I need my Django to access the serial port

I'm correctly using it via pyserial package the issue is that, every time I boot the OS I got the error of Access denied.

The only way to make it work is to grant access to the specific serial for everyone via `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Is there a way to let Django access the serial anyway, instead of let eveyone access it with `666`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out you need to add the User that manages Django deployment and execution to the `dialout` group with

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Restart or logout, login to see it work